# Problems on downloads in docker based on windowsservercore (Appveyor, Visual Studio 2017)

Tags: docker, appveyor, windows-container, windows-server-container

I have a small question about file downloads on `windowsservercore` docker image.
I have a small docker image listed here: https://github.com/EndurantDevs/sonarqube-mysql-windows-docker

As you can see - there are four similar Docker files: 2 versions of SonarQube that are based on 2 versions of Windows containers (`nanoserver` and `windowsservercore`, through `openjdk` image )

During the Build process, downloads of required files on `nanoserver` go well.

However, on `windowsservercore` images I get this problem:

```
Invoke-WebRequest : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error  occurred on a send. At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-WebRequest https://sonarsource.bintray.com/Distribution/sonarq ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:Htt     pWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShe     ll.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

**So, the issue appears on download of the same files from the same servers that work well from `nanoserver`.**

Applying all known fixes including the Tls12 didn't help.
I would assume this is a problem on the host machine on Appveyor side. However, even fixes for registry I tried didn't help also.

Here is builds information to compare: https://ci.appveyor.com/project/dnikolayev/sonarqube-mysql-windows-docker/build/1.0.53

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol` command before `Invoke-WebRequest` to display protocols enabled on docker instance and compare "good" and "bad" one. After comparison you can make a decision how to update SSL settings.

Most forgiving would be allow all by setting `[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = 'Ssl3', 'Tls', 'Tls11', 'Tls12'`. This will not necessary compromise your security as this will allow **client** to negotiate any security protocol with the server, but it will try use highest possible anyway. But sure you can be more restrictive and comparison of "good" and "bad" builds with `[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol` command will give you an idea.

Comment: I updated by extended string you gave, Build still goes. However, it started to work. Very funny, that nanoserver image works fine, but not windowsservercore: https://ci.appveyor.com/project/dnikolayev/sonarqube-mysql-windows-docker/build/1.0.58